# Search and store longitude and latitude cordinates to database codeigniter, Map not Loading

Tags: javascript, mysql, codeigniter, google-maps

Maps aren't loading on the page, plus the search text field doesn't seem to work, I'm quite stuck here

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#map {
    height: 100%;
}
.controls {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#pac-input {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 300px;
}
#pac-input:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
}
.pac-container {
    font-family: Roboto;
}
#type-selector {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4d90fe;
    padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
#target {
    width: 345px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: -33.8688,
            lng: 151.2195
        },
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current maps viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function () {
        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    var markers = [];
    // [START region_getplaces]
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // Clear out the old markers.
        markers.forEach(function (marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        });
        markers = [];

        // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        places.forEach(function (place) {
            var icon = {
                url: place.icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: icon,
                title: place.name,
                position: place.geometry.location
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (evt) {
                document.getElementById('coordinates').value = marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6);
            });
            markers.push(marker);
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                // Only geocodes have viewport.
                bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
    // [END region_getplaces]
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initAutocomplete);
```

HTML:

```
<input id="coordinates" type="text" size="30" />
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="map"></div>
```

I'd want to use the search from `<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">` and get coordinates into the `<input id="coordinates" type="text" size="30" />` so that I can store the coordinates into my database, but now The Map, doesn't load and the search box doesn't respond either.

Comment: Did you include your google map api keys?

Comment: What does the console say?